# QGIS 2 problems with Plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

When trying to access plugins I am told `Unable to open the Python console`.  When I start QGIS, the message also shows up but I don't know what it means.

The problem is that I have no access to the Add Delimited Text Layer plugin.

[image]

Comment: The tool Add Delimited Text Layer is available directly from the Layer menu, the plugin is not required.

Comment: as Willy already explained this error-message is misleading. you can use the Add Delimited Text Layer from the Layer menu and it works fine:-). No need to install it.

Comment: @Willy, Kurt: You are right, but the plugin is still in the Plugin Manager list. And from the error message, it seems that python does not work at all.

Comment: @Andre Joost: But I could load a CSV-file without any problem...

Answer (score 1):

The second error is reproducable, so I opened a ticket for that:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8635

But that does not yet solve the Python console error (which I don't get).

Answer (score 1):

I got this 'Unable to open the Python console' error when I installed 64bit QGIS2.0 and when my machine already had Python 2.7 32bit. When I uninstalled my 32bit Python installation, the error had gone. It is worth to check your standalone version of python if you have one!